# JSON.parse data with chinese character but output becomes "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON data that contains chinese characters which looks like this:

```
output = [{"name":"姓名"},{"name":"年齡"},{"name":"地址"}]
```

and I try to do the following:

```
var method = JSON.parse(output);
$.each(method, function(name, value) {
    alert(value.method);
}
```

Instead of returning 姓名, 年齡, and 地址, it returns undefined, undefined and undefined.

Any idea or help will be much appreciated! Thank you all in advance!

Comment: From your use of `$.each`, I take it you're using jQuery?

Comment: `output = [{"name":"姓名"},{"name":"年齡"},{"name":"地址"}]` isn't using JSON at all, and you wouldn't use `JSON.parse` on it. It's just a JavaScript array literal. If you have the ***text*** `[{"name":"姓名"},{"name":"年齡"},{"name":"地址"}]` in a file or coming back from an ajax request or something, *that* would be JSON and you would need to parse it.

Comment: Thank you very much T.J., you are correct that "output" is the result of a json_encode function returned from a separate php file. The strange thing is that the "output" values can be either chinese or english, i.e. 姓名 or name, 年齡 or age...etc, when the values are in english, I can perform alert(value.method) after JSON.parse(output) and see "name", "age"..., but if they are in chinese, the alert values become "undefined"...any idea of possible cause? Many thanks!

Comment: @ Wil: No, if the output is `[{"name":"english"}]`, you cannot alert `value.method` and have it be anything other than `undefined`. There is no `method` property on that object. If you think you're doing that, you're doing something you're not showing. Put together a [complete, self-contained example](http://sscce.org), put it in the question, and ideally do a live version as well on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net. qiu-deqing has given you the correct code in his/her answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

you miss the api of each()

```
var method = JSON.parse(output);
$.each(method, function(name, value) {
    alert(value.name); // value is an object {name: "地址"}
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much qiu-deqing too!!

Comment: 不客气 :) @T.J. Crowder is warm-hearted

Comment: *"you miss the api of each()"* How so? As far as I can tell, you are using each in exactly the same way as the OP does. The only difference is that you are accessing the correct property, but that doesn't have anything to do with `$.each`.